# Images Not Loading in Email from Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Have some images that are stored in my rails assets/images folder. I need to display these images in an email sent from my rails app. I am able to send email but the images appear as broken links.

My development.rb file is shown below:

```
config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'

config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
```

My Mailer View is shown below:

```
<div class = "container">
  <%= image_tag(asset_path('com_name.jpg')) %>
</div>

<div class = "container">
    <%= image_tag(asset_path('banner.png')) %>
</div>

<h4>Hi! This mail is to inform you that your request has been successfully processed and the processed output has been attached along with your mail for your perusal</h4>

<h4>Looking forward to serve you once again.</h4>

<h5>Thanks,</h5>
<h4>Team Introhive</h4>
```

What am I doing wrong here? In the original email source i see the image tag referencing the correct fingerprinted files too but still it seems to be appearing broken.Any Help Please?

Comment: use image_url instead of image_tag. image_url('banner.png')

Comment: @ShabiniRajadas This prints out the entire public url path in my mail doesnt render the images

Comment: Just use `image_tag('banner.png')`..

Comment: @GokulM That didnt Help either

Comment: add config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => your host } to your developement.rb( or if you use production mode thaen in production.rb) under environment and use image_tag('banner.png')

Comment: Do you precompiled the assets? Precompile it using       `rake assets:precompile` command

Comment: I have done that but still not resolved my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try the following,
In the mailer method,

For eg.

```
class NotifierMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def welcome(recipient)
    attachments.inline['photo.png'] = File.read('path/to/photo.png')
    mail(to: recipient, subject: "Here is what we look like")
  end
end
```

And in your views, use the following,

```
<%= image_tag attachments['photo.png'].url -%>
```

And if you want any options to be passed in you can use this,

```
<%= image_tag attachments['photo.png'].url, alt: 'Our Photo', class: 'photo' -%>
```

Please check the document http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html on inline images.

Answer (score 4):

As explained in [Action Mailer Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/action_mailer_basics.html#adding-images-in-action-mailer-views).

> Unlike controllers, the mailer instance doesn't have any context about the incoming request so you'll need to provide the `:asset_host` parameter yourself.
>
> As the `:asset_host` usually is consistent across the application you can configure it globally in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://example.com'
```

> Now you can display an image inside your email.

```
<%= image_tag 'image.jpg' %>
```

Comment: This answer fix my problem and was quick / easy

Comment: @Prakash - thank you.  I had this same problem and your answer fixed it.  Thank you, so much.